# Update already-mounted screen when you navigate back to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm making an app with React Native and Redux, and on one of my screens I have a state variable that I retrieve from the store on `componentDidMount()`, and then immediately save it in a local state variable for the screen. So my `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` methods look like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getA(); // this sets this.props.A
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.A && this.props.A){
    this.setState({
      A: this.props.A
    })
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**

If I navigate away from this screen and then navigate back, `this.props.A` still exists, but `this.state.A` does not. I understand why this occurs, but I'm wondering what the best practice is for re-setting `this.state.A` every time I navigate back to the screen like this.

**My Question:**

When a screen mounts, `componentDidMount()` gets triggered. Is there some event that gets triggered when you navigate back to an already-mounted component? I know I could do this by creating another state variable that I automatically toggle whenever I navigate, or could call `forceUpdate()` or something, but I want the cleanest solution possible. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for your navigation? One thing I am not clear on, you mention that your state is lost (_"this.props.A still exists, but this.state.A does not"_) you go on to say that the component doesn't unmount, why is your state lost in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The above way of declaration is not advisable.

> Initializing State from Props In most cases, this is an antipattern.
>   Don’t “copy props into state.” It creates a second source of truth for
>   your data, which usually leads to bugs. One source of truth is best.
>
> Components will already re-render when their props change, so there’s
>   no need to duplicate the props as state and then try to keep it up to
>   date.

Please follow this link https://daveceddia.com/where-initialize-state-react/.

You can just use props directly when you navigate back to already mounted component.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using React Navigation 3.0, there are some changes to how Drawer Navigator behaves from an earlier version.
As in React Navigation docs,

> Previously when using the drawer navigator screens would unmount when
>   inactive, and when you switch back to them you’d need to re-render the
>   entire thing. In tabs these stay in memory as you would expect, so
>   once you switch to the screen once it’s faster to go back there again
>   and you don’t lose your place in a scroll view or anything. Drawer now
>   behaves the same way, but you can go back to the old behavior if you
>   like by passing in `unmountInactiveRoutes: true` in the drawer
>   navigation configuration.

Just add `unmountInactiveRoutes: true` to navigation options. Like this,

```
const MainStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  //your routes
}, {
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: wp('69%'),
  unmountInactiveRoutes: true
}
```